# Javascript prepend to line in textarea on double click

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do:

1. Double click a line in a textarea.
2. Prevent text from being selected.
3. Prepend a dash to that line.

I know some basic jquery but can't seem to understand the lower level javascript that is required. Here is what I have so far:

```
$("textarea").dblclick(function() {

   //TODO: Prevent selection


   //TODO: Get the line number??


   //TODO: prepend a dash to the line
   // or replace the line with itself
   // plus the dash at the front??


});
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scooke/4zk5otvm/1/).

Comment: This is not a simple task in the slightest. To know the line selected you will have to delve in to textSelection ranges and assorted nastiness with regard to hard/soft new lines. I would suggest you look at the Rangy plugin as it would at least get you started.

Comment: Is the text in the textarea predefined or can the user add to it?  The reason why I say this is you are going to have to first get the amount of lines in the textarea as it stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a number of things you need to do, but something like this should be enough to get you started:

```
$("textarea").dblclick(function() {
    //first, get the position of the cursor
    var cursorPosition = $(this).prop("selectionStart");

    //get the text value at the cursor position
    var textValue = $(this).val().substr(cursorPosition,1);

    //use a loop to look backward until we find the first newline character \n
    while(textValue != '\n' && cursorPosition >= 0) {
        cursorPosition--;
        textValue = $(this).val().substr(cursorPosition,1);
    }
    //update the textarea, combining everything before the current position, a dash, and everything after the current position.
    $(this).val(($(this).val().substr(0,cursorPosition+1) + '-' + $(this).val().substr(cursorPosition+1)))

});
```

You can see an example in this JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/4zk5otvm/2/

There will probably be a lot more you need to add to this, depending on what you want to be able to do with the function and what limits you want to enforce, but that should be enough to get you started.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Also to prevent selection you can add in your css  `textarea::selection{
  background:none;}`  `textarea::-moz-selection{ background:none;}`

Answer (score 1):

I needed something similar, here's what you might've been looking for with vanilla JS (without jQuery or anything):

```
function dblClickEvt(obj) {
  let pos = obj.selectionStart;
  let text = obj.value;

  let lineStart = text.lastIndexOf("\n", pos);
  let lineEnd = text.indexOf("\n", pos);

  let before = ( lineStart === -1 ? '' : text.slice(0, lineStart + 1) ); // row(s) before incl. line break
  let after = '';

  if(lineEnd === -1) // -> last row is selected
    lineEnd = undefined; // because -1 would cause the selection to strip the last character
  else
    after = text.slice(lineEnd); // row(s) after the selection

  let selected = text.slice(lineStart + 1, lineEnd); // the selected row

  // write new value (manipulate before, selection a/o after if you want)
  obj.value = before + '-' + selected + after;

  // reset cursor position:
  obj.selectionStart = pos;
  obj.selectionEnd = pos;
}
```

Use the "ondblclick" attribute of your textarea to call the function:

```
<textarea ondblclick="dblClickEvt(this)"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This only supports modern browsers, if you want to support older browsers, then you need to get the method that calculates selectionStart. This is not fully tested and if you double click on a line that is selected, it toggles the dash. And when you set the new value, the selection goes away.

```js
$("textarea").on("dblclick", function (evt) { 

    var taValue = this.value;

    //if there is no text than there is nothing to do
    if(!taValue.length) return;

    //get the position of the selection (not supported old browsers)
    var se = this.selectionStart;  
    
    //find where the previous line break is located  (array lastIndexOf not supported old browsers)  
    //thinking about it, probably do not need to split... :)
    var loc = taValue.substr(0, se).split("").lastIndexOf("\n")+1;  
  
    //separate the text by characters
    var parts = taValue.split("");
     
    //if the character is a -, than remove it
    if (parts[loc]==="-") {  
        parts.splice(loc, 1);
    } else {  //else inject the -
        parts.splice(loc, 0, "-");      
    }
  
    //join the array back up into a string and set the value
    this.value = parts.join("");
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows=10 cols=30>FOO FOO FOO
BAR BAR BAR
CAKE CAKE CAKE
WORLD WORLD WORLD</textarea>
```